# Comparing results from two API calls and returning their difference in MEAN app

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean

> **EDIT**: Since I wasn't able to find a correct solution, I changed the
>   application's structure a bit and posted another question:
>   [Mongoose - find documents not in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486752/mongoose-find-documents-not-in-a-list)

I have a MEAN app with three models: `User`, `Task`, and for keeping track of which task is assigned to which user I have `UserTask`, which looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const autopopulate = require("mongoose-autopopulate");

const UserTaskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  completed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    autopopulate: true
  },
  taskId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Task",
    autopopulate: true
  }      
});
UserTaskSchema.plugin(autopopulate);

module.exports = mongoose.model("UserTask", UserTaskSchema);
```

In my frontend app I have AngularJS services and I already have functions for getting all users, all tasks, and tasks which are assigned to a particular user (by getting all `UserTasks` with given `userId`. For example:

```
// user-task.service.js
function getAllUserTasksForUser(userId) {
  return $http
    .get("http://localhost:3333/userTasks/byUserId/" + userId)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
}

// task-service.js
function getAllTasks() {
  return $http.get("http://localhost:3333/tasks").then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

Then I'm using this data in my controllers like this:

```
userTaskService
    .getAllUserTasksForUser($routeParams.id)
    .then(data => (vm.userTasks = data));
```

...and because of `autopopulate` plugin I have complete `User` and `Task` objects inside the `UserTasks` that I get. So far, so good.

Now I need to get all `Task`s which are **not** assigned to a particular `User`. I guess I should first get all `Task`s, then all `UserTasks` for a given `userId`, and then make some kind of difference, with some "where-not-in" kind of filter.

I'm still a newbie for all the MEAN components, I'm not familiar with all those `then()`s and promises and stuff... and I'm really not sure how to do this. I tried using multiple `then()`s but with no success. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can do at server/API side that will more efficient.

In client side, if you want to do then try below

```
var userid = $routeParams.id;
userTaskService
    .getAllTasks()
    .then((data) => {
        vm.userTasks = data.filter(task => task.userId !== userid)
    });
```

Comment: I will try this out, thanks. Just out of curiosity, can you edit your answer and also give me the idea how to do it at the server side?

Comment: Edit: Actually, this solution will not work. Here you will get the UserTasks, which represent only the tasks that are already assigned to some user. If there are Tasks which are unassigned, there won't be any UserTask entries with the corresponding taskId's...

Comment: Edit 2: Just an explanation. Assume that there are Users A, B, C and Tasks 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. If the User A is assigned to Tasks 1 and 2, and the User B is assigned to Tasks 2 and 3, then I will have the following UserTasks: {A,1}, {A,2}, {B,2}, {B,3}. According to your initial answer, for User B I would get back Tasks 1 and 2, because those are UserTask entries which don't have User B assigned. And what I really need are Tasks 1, 4 and 5.